# How to keep using disabled extension in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have Chome running on Linux. As you know from time to time Google disables some extensions without even offering the possibility to keep using them anyway even if they are marked as "containing malware".
It happened that Google just disabled one extension I use from time to time but I can still see the extension present in the browser and I assume extension files are still present on my system.

Is there a way to forcefully re-enable extensions that Google turned off due to "This extension contains malware."?

For example, is there a way to edit some extension files manually so that it I can reload edited files back into Chrome as "custom made extension" or something that can trick the browser?

That policy of Google forcing me not to use something they don't like it slowly but surely driving me mad. I mean, if I wanna be at risk, warn me but let me choose to be at risk if I wish and trust the publisher :)

Comment: Google doesn't disable extensions for no reason. Your primary focus should be to see why it was marked as malicious, not how to get around it. You could easily lose some private data or have a bitcoin miner,

Answer (score 1):

Chrome thinks it's a malware, maybe due to bad user reviews or something else, but I think this will work and you will be able to use it. Though you didn't tell that **what** extension you are trying to use, so I can't test it out.

- open chrome without internet
- go to `chrome://extensions/`
- check the `id` of that particular extension
- remove that extension
- open `/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions` (Assuming you have only one chrome profile)
- open the folder of that `id`
- inside you will find the folder with the version number
- create a folder with the name of the extension somewhere on your filesystem, e.g. `Downloads` or `Home` folder
- `copy` the **contents** of that version number folder into your newly created folder
- open `chrome://extensions/`, yes again..
- check `Developer Mode` at the top right
- click `Load Unpacked` and select your created extension folder

and now it should be working, since it's a user developed extension

Let me know if it worked!